# R Aggregate data frame sum and count in one step

Tags: r, dataframe, count, aggregate

I'm wondering if there's a way of doing the following in one step.

I had two columns, one with characters that are not unique and another with numbers.

I did:

```
sum<-(aggregate(x=df$numbers, by=list(df$char), FUN=sum)
sum$char <- sum$Group.1
sum$Group.1 <- NULL
df <- setDT(df)[, .N, char]
df <- merge(df,sum,by="char")
```

Wondering if there would be other ways, such as using `cast` that would be as simple, but one step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to create two new columns in the original dataset, use `:=` to assign the output to new columns after grouping by 'char' in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, c("Sum", "Count") := list(sum(Numbers), .N) , by = char]
```

But, if we need only a summarised output

```
setDT(df)[, .(Sum = sum(Numbers), Count = .N), by = char]
```